# Confusion on conservation of angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, precession

Can someone explain how angular momentum is conserved while at the same time precession in freely rotating objects happens?

It seems contradictory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular momentum is a much more complicated beast than linear momentum.
$\renewcommand{\tensor}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{#1}}
%% ugh, the \over arrows have different spacing than \vec
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}} 
$

With linear momentum for a solid object, the relationship between momentum and velocity is always the same: $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$. The momentum is always in the same direction as the velocity and the are related by a fixed ratio (ignoring complicated cases where the mass changes). That means if an object has the same momentum at two points in time the velocity must not change as well: $m\vec{v}= m\vec{v}' \Rightarrow \vec{v}=\vec{v}'$

But for angular momentum the relationship is $\vec{L} = \tensor{I}\vec{\omega}$. The first difference is that the angular momentum vector and the angular velocity vector don't necessarily point in the same direction. The second and most important difference is that the moment of inertia tensor $\tensor{I}$ can change, even for a perfectly rigid object! For anything shape more complicated than a sphere* if the object changes its orientation then its moment of inertia also changes.

That means that the object can change its angular velocity without changing its angular momentum if its moment of inertia also changes: you  go from $\vec{L} = \tensor{I}\vec{\omega}$ to $\vec{L} = \tensor{I}'\vec{\omega}'$, and $\vec{\omega}'$ doesn't have to be the same as $\vec{\omega}$ because $\tensor{I}'\ne \tensor{I}$.

Ultimately, rotating objects, even ones with no external torque, have much more freedom of movement than non-rotating objects. You get used to the idea of unforced movement being very simple when you study linear motion, but it's just not the case when you study rotational motion.

Comment: There is something not quite right in your notation $\vec{L} = \vec{I}\vec{\omega}$.

Comment: I suppose the notation here is to mark an object as a tensor. I is the moment of inertia tensor. omega is a vector which is a rank ( 0, 1) tensor. Though I agree it's odd.

Comment: Yes, I didn't feel like figuring out how to do a double-arrow for the moment of inertia tensor, but I wanted something to indicate that it is not just a scalar. If someone else knows how to do it go ahead and make the edit.

Comment: I see, the point is that both the inertia matrix and then angular velocity vector evolve while the angular momentum can remain fixed.

Comment: I assume that the asterisk on "more complicated than a sphere" was meant to recognize that some slightly more complicated objects, such as most (all?) uniform polyhedra, also have a moment of inertia that is independent of orientation.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, that is correct. The answer felt long already, but we can write it out here. "More complicated than a sphere" really means the that principal moments of the moment of inertia tensor are not all the same. Other highly symmetric objects may behave like a sphere and not precess.

Answer (score 0):

Pecession occurs when an external torque causes a continuous change in (the direction of) the angular momentum vector. (Nutation is a transient wobble induced by an impulsive torque.)

Answer (score -1):

The confusion is in the definition of precession.

One definition of precession is a changing orientation of angular momentum. This can only be the result of an external torque. In this sense, freely rotating objects do not precess. From the title of the question it is clear that the OP has this definition in mind.

A second definition is a changing orientation of the rotational axis. This is more conveniently defined as nutation. See https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precessie. For a sufficiently low symmetric tensor of inertia the axis of rotation can vary while the angular momentum is constant. According to this definition a free body can precess but it is preferable to say that it can **nutate**.

Comment: This is incorrect, as you can see in this demonstration on the International Space Station. Even with no external torques the rotation of the T-handle is quite complicated https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1n-HMSCDYtM

Comment: Freely rotating objects do precess according to Euler's equations, which are covered in most introductory texts to classical mechanics. You should check it out.

Comment: @VincentThacker Your comnent is only 50% correct.

Comment: @my2cts No, precession is defined as the change in the direction of the axis of rotation over time. From Wikipedia: "*Precession is a change in the orientation of the rotational axis of a rotating body*". The first definition does not make any sense. Nutation is a specific type of precession which is the change of the second Euler angle.

Comment: @VincentThacker I recommend the Dutch Wikipedia article instead. It is more accurate.

Comment: @my2cts Again, it makes no sense to me why something in Dutch language would be defined differently than in English language.

Comment: @VincentThacker I couldn't agree more. Why is the English text different, indeed.

Comment: @LukePritchett Thanks for pointing to this fascinating mechanical effect. Note that this does not qualify as precession according to e.g. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/precession.